# Delcaring template function without class keyword

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying template programming in C++-11.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
 * Function templates are special functions that can operate with generic types. This allows us to create a function template whose
 * functionality can be adapted to more than one type or class without repeating the entire code for each type.
 * In C++ this can be achieved using template parameters. A template parameter is a special kind of parameter that can be used to
 * pass a type as argument: just like regular function parameters can be used to pass values to a function, template parameters allow
 * to pass also types to a function. These function templates can use these parameters as if they were any other regular type.
 */

/* The format for declaring function templates with type parameters is:
 *   template <class identifier> function_declaration;
 *   template <typename identifier> function_declaration;
*/

template <class T>
T GetMax (T a, T b) {
    T result;
    result = (a>b)? a : b;
    return (result);
}

template<T>
T FindMaximum(T a, T b)
{
    T result;
    result = (a > b) ? a : b;
    return result;
}

int main () {
    int i=5, j=6;
    int k, c;
    long l=10, m=5;
    long n, d;


    k=GetMax<int>(i,j);
    n=GetMax<long>(l,m);

    cout << k << endl;
    cout << n << endl;

    c=FindMaximum<int>(j, i);
    d=FindMaximum<long>(l,m);

    cout << c << endl;
    cout << d << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

These two functions

```
    c=FindMaximum<int>(j, i);
    d=FindMaximum<long>(l,m);
```

gives an error

```
‘T’ has not been declared template<T>
```

But from the comment (which I copied from the tutorial, I understand that I can use a `class identifier` or a `typename identifier`.

What is wrong with my code. I do a declare a template function without the `class` keyword.

Comment: *" I can use a class identifier or a typename identifier"*. But, there, you don't use `class` nor `typename`.

Comment: With templates `typename` and `class` mean the same thing. Use one or the other.

Comment: It doesn't say use "a typename", but use the keyword `typename`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template declaration is missing the `class` or `typename` keyword.

Replace:

```
template<T>
T FindMaximum(T a, T b)
```

with:

```
template<typename T>
T FindMaximum(T a, T b)
-- OR --  
template<class T>
T FindMaximum(T a, T b)
```

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that I can use a class identifier or a typename identifier

Perfectly true, but you didn't use either.

```
template<T> <--- HERE it should be "class T" or "typename T"
T FindMaximum(T a, T b)
```